A block on a smooth rotating table
Assume a block is placed on a slightly rough table. Now that table starts to rotate about its center. Why does the block move towards the edge and fall off?
I heard somewhere that it is because of "Directional Inertia" or due to "Coriolis force".
I have no idea what they are. Please explain what they are, and why it happens.

The word smooth is ambiguous in this example.
If it means frictionless then the block will not move.
If it means a small frictional force acts on the block then because the block has inertia (resists acceleration) it attempts to travel along a trajectory that is as close to a straight line as possible. As the frictional force is small it is not large enough to change the direction of the block so that it will move in a circle.

Usual question. Why the -1 as it will help me in the future?
